# how can I change my currency in woocommerce google analytics pro

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, woocommerce, currency

Because my currency hasn't been defined in Google Analytics and also in this wordpress plugin ( woocommerce google analytics pro )  , so I'd like to send my website currency into dollar , consequently I could see my report in google analytics as dollar .

this plugin get my website currency as a event value , whereas currency in my website is different with both of them.

this is a snippet  of woocommerce google analytics pro plugin that I think that currency is defined  .

how should I change the code and match currency in website and google analytics ?

```
    /**
 * Checks the Google Analytics profiles for correct settings.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
private function check_analytics_profile_settings() {

    if ( $this->has_run_analytics_profile_checks ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! $this->is_plugin_settings() ) {
        return;
    }

    $integration = $this->get_integration();

    if ( 'yes' === $integration->get_option( 'use_manual_tracking_id' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! $integration->get_access_token() ) {
        return;
    }

    $analytics   = $integration->get_analytics();
    $account_id  = $integration->get_ga_account_id();
    $property_id = $integration->get_ga_property_id();

    if ( $account_id && $property_id ) {

        try {

            $profiles          = $analytics->management_profiles->listManagementProfiles( $account_id, $property_id );
            $ec_disabled       = array();
            $currency_mismatch = array();

            foreach ( $profiles as $profile ) {

                $profile_id           = $profile->getId();
                $property_internal_id = $profile->getInternalWebPropertyId();

                if ( ! $profile->getEnhancedECommerceTracking() ) {

                    $url  = "https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#management/Settings/a{$account_id}w{$property_internal_id}p{$profile_id}/%3Fm.page%3DEcommerceSettings/";
                    $link = '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">' . $profile->getName() . '</a>';

                    $ec_disabled[] = array(
                        'url'  => $url,
                        'link' => $link,
                    );
                }

                if ( $profile->getCurrency() !== get_woocommerce_currency() ) {

                    $url  = "https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#management/Settings/a{$account_id}w{$property_internal_id}p{$profile_id}/%3Fm.page%3DProfileSettings/";
                    $link = '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">' . $profile->getName() . '</a>';

                    $currency_mismatch[] = array(
                        'url'      => $url,
                        'link'     => $link,
                        'currency' => $profile->getCurrency(),
                    );
                }
            }

            if ( ! empty( $ec_disabled ) ) {

                if ( 1 === count( $ec_disabled ) ) {
                    /* translators: Placeholders: %1$s - <a> tag, %2$s - </a> tag */
                    $message = sprintf( __( 'WooCommerce Google Analytics Pro requires Enhanced Ecommerce to be enabled. Please enable Enhanced Ecommerce on your %1$sGoogle Analytics View%2$s.', 'woocommerce-google-analytics-pro' ), '<a href="' . $ec_disabled[0]['url'] . '" target="_blank">', '</a>' );

                } else {

                    $views   = '<ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', wp_list_pluck( $ec_disabled, 'link' ) ) . '</li></ul>';
                    /* translators: Placeholders: %s - a list of links */
                    $message = sprintf( __( 'WooCommerce Google Analytics Pro requires Enhanced Ecommerce to be enabled. Please enable Enhanced Ecommerce on the following Google Analytics Views: %s', 'woocommerce-google-analytics-pro' ), $views );
                }

                $this->get_admin_notice_handler()->add_admin_notice(
                    '<strong>' . $this->get_plugin_name() . ':</strong> ' .
                    $message,
                    'enhanced-ecommerce-not-enabled'
                );
            }

            if ( ! empty( $currency_mismatch ) ) {

                if ( 1 === count( $currency_mismatch ) ) {
                    /* translators: Placeholders: %1$s and %2$s - currency code, e.g. USD, %3$s - <a> tag, %4$s - </a> tag */
                    $message = sprintf( __( 'Your Google Analytics View currency (%1$s) does not match WooCommerce currency (%2$s). You can change it %3$son your Google Analytics View%4$s.', 'woocommerce-google-analytics-pro' ), $profile->getCurrency(), get_woocommerce_currency(), '<a href="' . $url . '" target="_blank">', '</a>' );
                } else {

                    $views   = '<ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', wp_list_pluck( $currency_mismatch, 'link' ) ) . '</li></ul>';
                    /* translators: Placeholders: %1$s - currency code, %2$s - a list of links */
                    $message = sprintf( __( 'Your Google Analytics Views currencies does not match WooCommerce currency (%1$s). You can change it on the following Google Analytics Views: %2$s', 'woocommerce-google-analytics-pro' ), get_woocommerce_currency(), $views );
                }

                $this->get_admin_notice_handler()->add_admin_notice(
                    '<strong>' . $this->get_plugin_name() . ':</strong> ' .
                    $message,
                    'analytics-currency-mismatch',
                    array( 'dismissible' => true, 'always_show_on_settings' => false )
                );
            }

            $this->has_run_analytics_profile_checks = true;

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {

            $this->log( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce Google Analytic's Pro will use [whatever currency has been set by your default WooCommerce settings](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shop-currency/). If you're using a custom currency, try the code below in your themes `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
     $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' );
     return $currencies;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = '$'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Plagiarizing is a stretch as I helped create many of the docs actually on WooCommerce.com. You can find it here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-custom-currency-symbol/

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Funny that you deleted your comment after you were proven wrong. Not only is this not plagiarizing as the code was written in the docs, but this is not a duplicate of the other question. I never even seen that other question/answer until you pointed it out. I worked for WooCommerce and wrote some of those docs. I know one or two things about the platform.

Comment: unfortunately it wouldn't work.
it still show $00.0 Revenue in Google Analytics after a purchase.